# Why does Django make migrations for help_text and verbose_name changes?

Tags: python, django, database-migration, django-1.7, django-1.9

When I change `help_text` or `verbose_name` for any of my model fields and run `python manage.py makemigrations`, it detects these changes and creates a new migration, say, `0002_xxxx.py`.

I am using PostgreSQL and I think these changes are irrelevant to my database (I wonder if a DBMS for which these changes are relevant exists at all).

Why does Django generate migrations for such changes? Is there an option to ignore them?

Can I apply the changes from `0002_xxxx.py` to the previous migration (`0001_initial.py`) manually and safely delete `0002_xxxx.py`?

Is there a way to update previous migration automatically?

Comment: This comment from andrewgodwin answers the question partly but I still want to be able to change `help_text` without needing to update migrations: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21498#comment:6

Answer (score 26):

You can [squash it with the previous migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing), sure.

Or if you don't want to output those migrations at all, you can override the `makemigrations` and `migrate` command by putting this in `management/commands/makemigrations.py` in your app:

```
from django.core.management.commands.makemigrations import Command
from django.db import models

IGNORED_ATTRS = ['verbose_name', 'help_text', 'choices']

original_deconstruct = models.Field.deconstruct

def new_deconstruct(self):
  name, path, args, kwargs = original_deconstruct(self)
  for attr in IGNORED_ATTRS:
    kwargs.pop(attr, None)
  return name, path, args, kwargs

models.Field.deconstruct = new_deconstruct
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out!  Seems so obvious after the fact.  This is a philosophical thing for some (complete migrations);  that's nice in theory except it doesn't work in practice.  Especially with help_text, choices, and `storage`!  Our storage manager  & path is determined at runtime so... what, you want me to make a fake storage for migrations?  Gah.  This solves it... separate runtime concerns from model concerns, as it should be.

Comment: You'll probably want to do this for the `migrate` command as well, to avoid the "Your models have changes that are not yet reflected" warning. I moved `new_deconstruct` to `__init__.py` and just assigned `models.Field.deconstruct = new_deconstruct` for both commands in separate files.

Answer (score 15):

[This ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21498) addressed the problem.

If you have changed only `help_text` & django generates a new migration; then you can apply changes from latest migration to previous migration and delete the latest migration.

Just change the `help_text` in the previous migration to help_text present in latest migration and delete the latest migration file. Make sure to remove corresponding `*.pyc`  file if it is present. Otherwise an exception will be raised.

Answer (score 9):

To avoid unnecessary migrations You can do as follows:

1. Subclass field that causes migration
2. Write custom deconstruct method inside that field
3. Profit

Example:

```python
from django.db import models

class CustomCharField(models.CharField):  # or any other field

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(CustomCharField, self).deconstruct()
        # exclude all fields you dont want to cause migration, my example below:
        if 'help_text' in kwargs:
            del kwargs['help_text']
        if 'verbose_name' in kwargs:
            del kwargs['verbose_name']
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

As @ChillarAnand noted there is a ticket solving this issue but until now (django 1.9.1) the migrations commands were not fixed.

The least intrusive way of fixing it is to create your own `maketranslatedmigrations` command in `<your-project>/management/commands/maketranslatedmigrations.py` as

```
#coding: utf-8

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management.commands.makemigrations import Command as MakeMigrations


class Command(MakeMigrations):
    leave_locale_alone = True
    can_import_settings = True

    def handle(self, *app_labels, **options):
        super(Command, self).handle(*app_labels, **options)
```

And then you can use it exactly the same as original makemigrations.

P.S. Don't forget to add `__init__.py` files everywhere on the path

Comment: The original question was about `makemigrations`, not `maketranslations`.

Answer (score 1):

I have written custom module for that purpose

All you need is to save it in some utils/models.db and in all your models instead of `from django.db import models` write `from utils import models`

If somebody is interested in it I can write a component and publish it on pypi

UPD: try this https://github.com/FeroxTL/django-migration-control

`# models.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from types import FunctionType
from django.db import models


class NoMigrateMixin(object):
    """
    Позволяет исключить из миграций различные поля
    """
    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(NoMigrateMixin, self).deconstruct()
        kwargs.pop('help_text', None)
        kwargs.pop('verbose_name', None)
        return name, path, args, kwargs


# =============================================================================
# DJANGO CLASSES
# =============================================================================

for name, cls in models.__dict__.items():
    if isinstance(cls, type):
        if issubclass(cls, models.Field):
            # Поля
            globals()[name] = type(name, (NoMigrateMixin, cls), {})
        else:
            # Всякие менеджеры
            globals()[name] = cls
    elif isinstance(cls, FunctionType):
        # Прочие функции
        globals()[name] = cls
```

Answer (score 1):

The ticket that ChillarAnand mentions is very helpfull, but at final of changelog, I did not realize if it was fixed or not, or it was fixed in newest version of Django.

So, due to I did not found any solution for Django 1.9.13, I added a little hack to `settings.py`:

```
if 'makemigrations' in sys.argv:
    USE_I18N = False
    USE_L10N = False
```

Not elegant, but it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Stop to generate migrations files when changes verbose_name or verbose_name_plural in any of your model fields.

In a new file like src/monkey_patching/django/db/migrations/operations/change_model_options.py add this:

```py
from django.db.migrations.operations import models

models.AlterModelOptions.ALTER_OPTION_KEYS = [
    "base_manager_name",
    "default_manager_name",
    "get_latest_by",
    "managed",
    "ordering",
    "permissions",
    "default_permissions",
    "select_on_save",
    # "verbose_name",
    # "verbose_name_plural",
]
```

Tested in django 1.11.10.

Comment: but can you just show how this is used ? It seems not related anyhow to the question.

Answer (score 0):

From Django 2.X, using `ugettext_lazy` instead of `ugettext` or `gettext` fixes it.