# Django migrations and customizable reusable apps

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-apps

I started writing my first reusable app about 3 weeks ago, and I'm having troubles to deal with migrations.

I want some points of my app to be customizable. Thus I have a [`conf` submodule](https://github.com/Aladom/django-mailing/blob/6260556aa11128d6ecdb514b5a3fbd8c823fef60/mailing/conf.py) that defines custom settings and assign the reasonable defaults that will fit most cases.

This leads some of my model fields to look like this:

```
attachment = models.FilePathField(
    path=conf.ATTACHMENTS_DIR, recursive=True)

template_file = models.FileField(
    upload_to=conf.TEMPLATES_UPLOAD_DIR, blank=True)

prefix_subject = models.BooleanField(
    default=True, verbose_name=_("prefix subject"),
    help_text=_(
        "Whether to prefix the subject with \"{}\" or not."
    ).format(conf.SUBJECT_PREFIX))
```

Unfortunately, on projects using this app, this causes `django-admin makemigrations` to create migrations for it every time a setting changes. Or even, the first time they install the app for settings which default value depends on the host system.

I'm more than doubtful about the legitimacy of a project creating its own migrations inside his copy of an app. But if I'm wrong, tell me.

For `prefix_subject` in the above sample, I solved the issue with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29233569/1529346). Considering that losing the `help_text` information in migrations was not very effective.

However, I'm not sure this is a suitable solution for all/most cases. Is it?

I thought about another solution that seems to work. This solution is to manually edit migrations and replace evaluated settings by the variable itself.

For instance, I would replace this:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='MailStaticAttachment',
    fields=[
        ('id', ...),
        ('filename', ...)
        ('mime_type', ...)
        ('attachment', models.FilePathField(path='/home/antoine/Workspace/django-mailing/static/mailing/attachments', recursive=True, verbose_name='file')),
    ],
    options={...}
),
```

With :

```
from ..conf import ATTACHMENTS_DIR

migrations.CreateModel(
    name='MailStaticAttachment',
    fields=[
        ('id', ...),
        ('filename', ...)
        ('mime_type', ...)
        ('attachment', models.FilePathField(path=ATTACHMENTS_DIR, recursive=True, verbose_name='file')),
    ],
    options={...}
),
```

Does it look like a good solution to you?

What do you advise to do in such cases?

I think both `Field.help_text`, `FilePathField.path` and `FileField.upload_to` attributes are not used to create SQL statements. So in this case, there should not be specific issues due to "ignoring them in migrations". But what if I, hypothetically, want a customizable `Field.default`, `Field.db_column` or `CharField.max_length` for instance? That's probably a very bad idea that have no practical interest, but that's the only hypothetical situation I can find. :P I guess in this case it would be better to provide an abstract base model, intended to be extended by the host project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the design of `django.db.migration` it was decided that all field attributes were to be tracked even if they didn't affect their schema representation.

For the `upload_to` case I suggest you simply pass a function defined at a module level [as documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

```
import os

def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join([conf.TEMPLATES_UPLOAD_DIR, filename])
```

For the `path` and `help_text` I suggest you use an approach similar to what I did with [`django-sundial`](https://github.com/charettes/django-sundial/blob/2db2be7a2f1ae1f68bb3048ce98ec27b0259a1d8/sundial/zones.py#L40-L58) to provide configurable defaults. You'll just have to make sure you pass an instance of a class with a [`deconstruct()` method returning the appropriate parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method).

```
from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class StringConfReference(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(conf, self.name)

    def deconstruct(self):
        return "%s.%s" % (__name__, self.__class__.__name__), (self.name,), {}


attachment = models.FilePathField(
    path=StringConfReference('ATTACHMENT_DIR'), recursive=True
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expect a better solution. Here is the patch I applied: https://github.com/Aladom/django-mailing/commit/78ffcb81eea5e01d6e5ff112d8548fed9d1063f3 The resulting migration looks good. :)

Comment: Yeah using `deconstructible` is even better. The reason why I suggested using `python_2_unicode_compatible` is that if one of your referenced settings contains non-ascii characters it's going to crash on Python 2.

Comment: Yep. I decided not to bother about Python 2 compatibility however. I think Python 3 is widely adopted enough. Even django will drop python 2 support in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Unfortunately, django logic uses `os.listdir(path)` which requires `path` to be a string, bytes or integer instance. I'm trying to fix this.

Comment: I opened a new question about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35632376/django-migrations-and-deconstructible-string