# Is verbose_name_plural stored in any django table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Anyone knows if verbose_name_plural is stored in any django table?

I mean, is this literal used in some of the django_migrations, auth_xxxx, ... tables when we apply a migration?

Comment: Verbose names are not stored in the database, they are purely used for relational lookups.

Comment: Ok. I wonder why is written in the migration file when I make a migrations of the models...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Django generate migrations for help\_text and verbose\_name changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503826/why-does-django-generate-migrations-for-help-text-and-verbose-name-changes)