# Django model dynamic choices migration

Tags: django

I have a model charfield which has dynamic choices

```
class MachineChoices(object):
    def get_machine_choices(self):
        # call external service to get a full list of machines
        ...

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.get_machine_choices()

class ExceptionMapping(models.Model):
    machine_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=MachineChoices())
```

My problem is that when I run `makemigrations` it will generate a migration for the field with all the choices.

How do I get around this without such gigantic migration. Deleting this migration manually each time running `makemigrations` is a pain in the butt.

Please Note:
I am asking why this is happening as I have already asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152633/why-does-django-1-7-creates-migrations-for-changes-in-field-choices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems with migrations, I solved them by executing different code depending if the current process is related to migration or not, as you can see in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535983/migration-clashes-with-forms-py).

In your case, you could do something like that:

```
class ExceptionMapping(models.Model):
    import sys
    if 'makemigrations' not in sys.argv and 'migrate' not in sys.argv:
        machine_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, choices=MachineChoices())
    else:
        machine_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I am agree that this solution is a bit hacky, but it works.

Comment: thank you for the hint, I was thinking about the same approach but was expecting a proper migration action flag in django, anyway this looks like the best work around so far.